# time between touch in and touch up

Tags: iphone, time

i have application view with nine icons on each page, i want to call a function when a certain icon is pressed for certain amount of time. similarly i want to do this with a cell in UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable NSTimer on touchesBegan:withEvent and disable it on touchesEnded:withEvent.

Answer (score 0):

For the icons view have used the TouchDown and TouchUpInside event to acomplish,

Used
timeBetweenTouchRelease = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; when TouchDown

and Used the following
timeBetweenTouchRelease = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - timeBetweenTouchRelease;

when TouchUpInside.

Still having problem with tablecell, i guess when using touch begin and end user may move his finger so that means user may have moved from one cell to another.

Comment: I think, that if your tableView is scrollable, then user cannot move finger to the other row)

Answer (score 0):

The button is easier because of the TouchUpInside and TouchDown events you can react to.

For a cell, you'd probably have to start a timer in setHighlighted:, and disable the timer when setHighlighted was called to unhighlight.